# Pressing "Enter" to print value to Console Log

Tags: javascript, if-statement, input, keydown, console.log

When I input a value in to a text box on the page the console log calls the else condition in my if statement even if I type "yes" in to the text box. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Choose your own adventure </title>
        <meta charset= "utf-8">
        <script src= "choose1.js"></script>
        <link type= "text/css" rel= "stylesheet" href= "choose1.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> What do you do? </p>
            <input type= "text" id= "decision" name= "decision" onkeydown=  "if(event.keyCode === 13) confirm()" />
        </p>
    </body>
</html>

//choose1.js//
function confirm(){
    var begin= document.getElementById("decision");
    if(begin === "yes") {
        console.log("Success!");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Failure");
    }
}
```

Comment: The *element* that you are fetching can never ve equal to a *string*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `begin` is pointing at the `<input>` element itself, not its contents.  You need to get hold of the value:

```
var begin= document.getElementById("decision").value;
```

Also, note that there is already a top-level function [called `confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm), you may want to consider renaming yours so you don't clash.

Answer (score 0):

wrong in javascript code.
begin object is input element, so if you want to check text in input then call begin.value
code:

```
function confirm(){
    var begin= document.getElementById("decision");
    if(begin.value == "yes") {
        console.log("Success!");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Failure");
    }
}
```